# Images are not showing on Django backend server

Tags: python, django

this is my Django project tree when i upload my image on Django form after that images are not visibal plz help me to solve this :

```
project/
   backend/
      app/
         __init__.py
         admin.py
         models.py
         urls.py
         view.py
      backend/
         __init__.py
         settings.py
         urls.py
         views.py
         wsgi.py
      static/
         AWS.png
```

Inside settings.py I have:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT= os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

my urls.py file :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('app.urls')),
]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Do you serve image files from the static folder, I mean static/AWS.png ??

Comment: Do you set `enctype` of your `form` element to `multipart/form-data` when rendering the template? Do you pass `request.FILES` to the form before form validation?

Answer (score 1):

Save images under folder media.
Ensure the media root is connected to that folder.

If you are still unable to see them, ensure your static files server is serving them correctly.
Opening up the browser inspection tools and viewing the requests will give you some introspective information.

Common errors with badly configured static server/media root:

1. **Images not found** ( the image is saved in a place where you are not
   expecting it)
2. **Forbidden permission** to serve image (add permissions to static server
   group)